# Calling dlclose on a handle returned by dlopen(NULL)

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I'm getting a handle to the main module of my executable using `dlopen(NULL)` as below.

```
void *handle = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW);
```

Should I be calling a `dlclose(handle)` to decrement the ref-count to the main module?

Answer (score 0):

From the manpage:

```
   dlclose()
       The  function  dlclose()  decrements the reference count on the dynamic
       library handle handle.  If the reference count drops  to  zero  and  no
       other  loaded  libraries use symbols in it, then the dynamic library is
       unloaded.
```

Tho I bet it is noop when you call it for "main" handle